# css toggle with transition effect for expanding div - set max-height to infinity alternative

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, transition

There is a simple html+css+js code to expand/collapse div with a 1-second effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/zf1rd38y/3/

Css code looks simple:

```
.smalldesc {
  max-height: 52px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.smalldesc.expand {
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

The issue is here you see the `max-height` has a fixed value for `.smalldesc.expand` (but if the text is long enough, then not all text is displayed when expanded).
If I set `max-height: none;` instead, then `transition: all 1s ease;` doesn't work.

Any ideas how to make it perfectly work for a very long text?

Comment: Not with CSS. Any transition needs a number to transition to. `auto` is not a number so it won't work. You'd need JS to calculate the height you want and transition to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the view height ('vh', e.g. `max-height: 100vh`) seems to do the trick.

[See also](https://kooi.dev/showFiddle/hskgwefz)

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () =>
  document.querySelector(`.smalldesc`).classList.toggle(`expand`));
```

```css
.smalldesc {
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}

.smalldesc.expand {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  First text goes here.
</h2>
<div class="smalldesc">
  <a href="#">Read More</a>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with ...</p>
</div>
<h2>
  Another text goes here.
</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try max-height: 1000px; see below example

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.smalldesc').classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

```css
.smalldesc {
  max-height: 52px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.smalldesc.expand {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
First text goes here.
</h2>
<div class="smalldesc">
  <a href="#">Read More</a>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
    unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
    the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
    unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
    the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
    unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
    the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<h2>
Another text goes here.
</h2>
```